# 8048 movp instruction

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to understand the `MOVP` and `MOVP3` instruction of 8048 microcontroller. Now in manuals no specific, clear example is given. What are the functions of these instructions?

- `MOVP A, @A`--> move program data in current page in accumulator, which locations data is copied here?
- `MOVP3 A,@A`--> Here also same is the question?

And in manual it's given ---"instructions such as `MOVP` and `MOVP3` allow easy access to data 'lookup' tables". Now what is the meaning of it? Lookup table all the entries must be needed but here only 1 location is copied(?).

Comment: Please add a link to the device's datasheet where you found this information.

Comment: [page 79](http://www.sharpmz.org/download/8048.pdf)

Comment: [page 38](http://home.mnet-online.de/al/mcs-48/mcs-48.pdf)

Comment: which information? the "instructions such as MOVP and MOVP3 allow....lookup tables"

Comment: grokking the MCS-48 manual. Page-6.Top left.

Comment: the link- //home.mnet-online.de/al/mcs-48/mcs-48.pdf

Comment: An example: You could use a lookup table for example to 'calculate' the square root of a number. If you have a given number '64' as input, you could load the 64th byte from the table and that would hold the number 8. You only need a single byte as input and the solution is a single byte as ouput.
You pre-calculate the contents of the table and keep it in ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've used 8048, and I don't have one available right now, so pardon me if this is a bit incomplete...

Like the 8051 that came later, the 8048 has several address spaces. *Data Memory* address 0 is a physically different piece of memory from *Program Memory* address 0. The later 8031/8032/8051/8052 replaced the `MOVP` and `MOVP3` (move from program) instructions with a single `MOVC`  (move from code) instruction, and a 16-bit data pointer. But the 8048 only has 8-bit registers, so it has to do some extra work to determine the full address in *program memory*.

The 8048 `MOVP` instruction is similar to the later 8051 `MOVC` instruction, loading a constant value from a location in the *Program Memory* address space. This is useful for selecting a value from a constant table of values.

The *Program Memory* is organized in several pages, starting with page 0. For short sequences of data, like loading a "hello world" string, it was common practice to put the constant data immediately after the subroutine, so that the constant data would be in the same *program memory* page as the subroutine that requires that data. The `MOVP` instruction is used to access that data.

But for larger tables, or for tables that might need to be accessed from any subroutine, the `MOVP3` instruction was used. `MOVP3` is just like `MOVP` except the data comes from page 3 of the *program memory* address space.

`MOVP` instruction forms the full address in *program memory* by combining the 8 bits of register A with the uppper part of the address where the `MOVP` instruction itself is being executed from. Put in terms of a C language expresssion, the *program memory* address would be `((programCounterAddress &~ 0x0FF) | regA_before)` Then the value read from that *program memory* address, becomes the new value of register A.

`MOVP3` instruction forms the full address in *program memory* by combining the 8 bits of register A with the uppper part of the address of page 3, 0x0300, regardless of the address the `MOVP3` instruction itself is being executed from. Then the value read from *program memory* address `(0x300 | regA_before)` becomes the new value of register A.

Comment: So we store table in page-3. Then as per our need we fetch data from it one by one using move instruction. Page-3 gives global access. So this is the idea.

Comment: :what is((PC address & 0x0FF)|regA_before)?

Comment: Just trying to explain how the program memory address is formed; hard to get the notation clear. The program memory needs more address bits than register A can hold. So the upper address bits come from the address where MOVP is executing. If MOVP is assembled at address 0x217 and register A contains 0x35 before the MOVP, then after MOVP then register A will contain whatever was assembled at address 0x235. Because (0x217 & 0x0FF) gives the upper bits as 0x200, and combining with the 0x35 from register A gives 0x235.

Comment: I assume you know C bitwise operators... `&` is boolean AND, `|` is boolean OR; useful for clearing and setting bits.

Comment: :0x217 & 0x0FF = 0x017 isn't it?

Comment: whoops... good catch, will edit...  (0x217 &~ 0x0FF) was what I was thinking ( `~` is bitwise NOT ). Could also (0x217 & 0xFF00).